# Running executables without using rosrun or roslaunch?

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**MY QUESTION :**

Do ROS topics  still properly communicate (subscribe/publish) in the following situation, even though I DID NOT run executables by rosrun/roslaunch?

If not, is there way to run ROS executables without using rosrun/roslaunch?

**SITUATION :**

By running `catkin biuld` ,
executables are created as (~/catkin_ws/devel/lib/PROJECT_NAME/sample_node)

If I try to run the execuatble as follows, it prints seemingly okay results on screen.

```
./catkin_ws/devel/lib/<PROJECT_NAME>/sample_node
```

(`roscore` runs somewhere anyway.)

**NECESSITY :**

I want to add ROS publish function in my pre-developed code, which cannot be run by rosrun/roslaunch because it contains other pthreads.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278547/running-executables-without-using-rosrun-or-roslaunch-??/) by [bkjung](https://answers.ros.org/users/33109/bkjung/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-02**:
I've done it with Python and didn't have any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've executed the binary files of ROS c++ nodes directly (without using rosrun or roslaunch) without any problems in the past, as long as your environment variables are set correctly this should work without any problems.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2